# Querying timestamp data in Athena when the timestamp format in the underlying JSON files has changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, aws-glue

I'm querying data in AWS Athena from JSON files stored in S3. I've loaded all the JSON files into Athena using AWS Glue, and it's been working perfectly so far. However, the timestamp formatting has changed in the JSON files from

```
2018-03-23 15:00:30.998
```

to

```
2018-08-29T07:59:50.568Z
```

So the table ends up having entries like this

```
2018-08-29T07:59:42.803Z
2018-08-29T07:59:42.802Z
2018-08-29T07:59:32.500Z
2018-03-23 15:03:43.232
2018-03-23 15:03:44.697
2018-03-23 15:04:11.951
```

This results in parsing errors when I try to run queries against the full DB.

How do I accommodate this in AWS Glue (or Athena), so I don't have to split up the data when querying? I've tried looking into custom classifiers, but I'm unsure of how to use them in this particular case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you map your timestamp values as `varchar`? Then you would be able to parse them explicitly in SQL (or defining a VIEW that does that), using CASE statement, checking which format particular value is in.

Comment: That also seems to be working. But I actually ended up unifying the data instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to unify the data. If you decide to use "2018-08-29T07:59:50.568Z" format you can read such data by using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe library with the following serde property:  'timestamp.formats'='yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what you mean with "unity the data"?

Comment: As you mentioned you have the timestamp column with two formats (2018-08-29T07:59:42.803Z and 2018-03-23 15:03:44.697). You have to unify the data and use only one format.